# Redirecting http link to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So Im redirecting an old url that uses HTTP protocol for SEO purposes. Problem is that I can't redirect it without an extra step that I made. In that step I wrote these three lines in htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The problem is that there is an extra step in redirecting. The link is first redirected to HTTPS and then to the right redirected page. Can I eliminate the middle step when it firstly changes HTTP to HTTPS protocol.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html" [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml" [L]
</IfModule>
```

Pic of the steps:

[image]

Comment: _"The link is first redirected to HTTPS and then to the right redirected page."_ - not sure what that is actually supposed to mean. Please add more info - example URLs and what redirects that causes, and where in your rewrite configuration you placed this, if there is more than just what you have currently shown above.

Comment: http://www.veckonjev.si/odstranitev-dpf-filtra/ this link should redirect to  https://www.veckonjev.si/dpf-filter/ .  But the rules that I wrote first adds HTTPS to first link and then redirects to second link.

Comment: Please show your complete rewrite setup.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: I can't see anything in there would cause the redirect from `/odstranitev-dpf-filtra` to `/dpf-filter/`. So I am guessing it is WordPress performing that redirect?

Comment: Yes its a plugin 301 redirects, sorry I didn't clarify that before

Comment: Then you're probably going to have a hard time combining both into one redirect. You would basically have to know which URLs to let "pass" in your .htaccess, so that you don't redirect those to HTTPS from there, but let the HTTP request for `http://www.veckonjev.si/odstranitev-dpf-filtra/` pass through to WP unmodified instead. And then let the plugin redirect to the new URL (which should be a HTTPS URL automatically, if you have set your site address correctly.)

Comment: But if you need to "know" these URLs in the .htaccess in the first place, then you might as well implement those redirects right there, instead of using the plugin ...

Comment: Do you think that .htacces file can override the plugins settings, if so, what kind of rule should I implement in .htacces file?

Comment: Your options are to either, as I said, let those requests pass through (so you would need a RewriteCond, that lets the HTTPS redirect rule _not_ apply for the request path `/odstranitev-dpf-filtra/`), or go the other direction - and explicitly redirect `/odstranitev-dpf-filtra/` to `https://www.veckonjev.si/dpf-filter/` from your .htaccess, _before_ the "general" HTTP -> HTTPS redirect, and thereby completely forgo the plugin.

Comment: So I've deleted the first three lines and just added this: RewriteRule ^odstranitev-dpf-filtra/?$ https://www.veckonjev.si/dpf-filter/ [R=301,L] . And it now redirects in in one step. Thanks for the help @CBroe , you re a true BRO indeed :D

Comment: But that's a redirect for that one specific URL only. If you still want a general HTTP -> HTTPS redirect for all _other_ URLs, you need to keep those lines.

Comment: It was just this http url that was causing problems. all others are HTTPS